# How to insert a <video> tag inside tinymce editor without replacing it to <img />?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce-4

I'am trying to insert a `<video>` tag inside tinymce editor, but it converts it to `<img>` tag, is it possible to leave that `<video>` tag without replacing it with `<img>` tag?, cause I want to allow a video playing inside tinymce while the user is editing...

Answer (score 4):

You nead change your extended_valid_elements settings on tinyMCE.init();

```
extended_valid_elements : "video[controls|preload|width|height|data-setup],source[src|type]"
```